# Compile Python 3.4 Code into EXE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

I'm trying to compile my Python 3.4 code into an exe, but I can't seem to find a suitable program for doing so.
Here's my code in test.py:

```
print ("hi")
```

I've tried using cx_Freeze and Nuitka, but the two only seem to support Python 3.3 and lower (cx_Freeze doesn't install, and Nuitka errors out.) Alternatives such as py2exe don't even go to Python 3, so I'm unsure of any other options I have available. So to summarize, what program can I use to compile my Python 3.4 code into a (preferably) single executable? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: the new cx_Freeze version has been fixed to work with Python 3.4